# Reformat Array of objects using array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I receive the result of an API call with the following array, I am trying to reformat this Array from:

```
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Item 1",
    section: { name: "Section A" }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Item 2",
    section: { name: "Section A" }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Item 3",
    section: { name: "Section A" }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Item 4",
    section: { name: "Section B" }
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Item 5",
    section: { name: "Section B" }
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Item 6",
    section: { name: "Section C" }
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Item 7",
    section: { name: "Section C" }
  }
];
```

To Array this:

```
const items = [
      {
        section: "Section A",
        items: [
          {
            id: 1,
            item: "Item 1"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            item: "Item 2"
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            item: "Item 3"
          }]
      },
      {
        section: "Section B",
        items: [
          {
            id: 4,
            item: "Item 4"
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            item: "Item 5"
          }]
      },
      {
        section: "Section C",
        items: [
          {
            id: 6,
            item: "Item 6"
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            item: "Item 7"
          }]
      },
    ]
```

I have tried the following function:

```
const result = Array.from(new Set(items.map(s => s.section.name)))
      .map(section => {
        return {
          section: section,
          items: Array.from(new Set(items.map(function (item) {
            if (item.section.name === section) {
              return item.name
            }
          }
          )))
        }
      })
```

This gives me the following result, which is close but I am not sure why I am getting the undefined values?

```
//[{section: "Section A", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", undefined]},{section: "Section B", items:[undefined, "Item 4", "Item 5"]},{section: "Section C", items: [undefined, "Item 6", "Item 7"]}]
```

Can anyone assist me to correct this function or suggest a better approach?

Comment: you're getting undefined because your `.map` when iterating over items returns undefined if your condition is not met (as you are even omitting any return if your condition is not met). A small suggestion would be to use `.reduce` at that point.

Comment: Did you try posting on ArrayOfObjectsOverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an object for grouping and get the values as result.

```js
const
    items = [{ id: 1, name: "Item 1", section: { name: "Section A" } }, { id: 2, name: "Item 2", section: { name: "Section A" } }, { id: 3, name: "Item 3", section: { name: "Section A" } }, { id: 4, name: "Item 4", section: { name: "Section B" } }, { id: 5, name: "Item 5", section: { name: "Section B" } }, { id: 6, name: "Item 6", section: { name: "Section C" } }, { id: 7, name: "Item 7", section: { name: "Section C" } }],
     result = Object.values(items.reduce((r, { section: { name: section }, ...item }) => {
        if (!r[section]) r[section] = { section, items: [] };
        r[section].items.push(item);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array` prototype methods `reduce()` and `findIndex()` 
like this:

```js
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Item 1",
    section: { name: "Section A" }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Item 2",
    section: { name: "Section A" }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Item 3",
    section: { name: "Section A" }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Item 4",
    section: { name: "Section B" }
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Item 5",
    section: { name: "Section B" }
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Item 6",
    section: { name: "Section C" }
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Item 7",
    section: { name: "Section C" }
  }
];

const res = items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const index = acc && acc.findIndex(({ section }) => section === curr.section.name) 
  if(index !== -1) {
    acc[index].items.push({ id: curr.id, item: curr.name });
  }
  else {
    acc.push({section: curr.section.name, items: [{ id: curr.id, item: curr.name }]});
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```